# How strong is an oracle that avoid don't-halt

Tags: turing-machines, computability, oracle-machines

Consider such an oracle:

> Given a turing machine[1], return the halting state it falls on, or arbitary result(but don't stuck in) if the TM doesn't halt.

1. How strong is a TM with the oracle?
2. Can the oracle exist(or does the question always have an answer) if change [1] into a TM with the oracle?

Some results I get:

1. It's as strong as a TM with oracle that compare running time of two programs, or arbitary returned value if both don't halt.
2. If the oracle returns integer the TM returns(may need to define a way it outputs integer), or arbitary integer if it doesn't halt, we can solve the halting problem by getting the runtime and check. However, currently I can't output from the oracle a string of any finite length if the length can be arbitary long, promising it's finite.

([Moved to here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317377))

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump).

Comment: @dkaeae How does that help?

Comment: Your oracle is not computable. I would guess that it is strictly weaker than a halting oracle, that is, you cannot solve the halting problem with an oracle to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I made a deeply silly mistake in my previous answer. Below what I've done is answered the question, then explained how two variations of the question - which I originally conflated with the actual question - yield a very different answer.

---

An oracle of the type you describe computes the halting problem (and conversely every oracle computing the halting problem computes an oracle of your type).

- Suppose $x$ computes the halting problem. Without loss of generality, we may take $x$ to literally *be* the halting problem. Then we can compute an $f$ as desired by simply taking an input $e$, asking $x$ whether $T_e(e)$ halts, and (i) if the answer is no, halt and output $0$ and (ii) if the answer is yes, run $T_e$ until it halts and output the result.
- Conversely, suppose $f$ has the desired property. There is a total computable function $h$ such that for all $e$ if $T_e(e)$ halts, then $T_{h(e)}(h(e))$ halts and gives the runtime of $T_e(e)$. Now to tell whether $T_e(e)$ halts we simply run $T_e(e)$ for $f(h(e))$-many steps.

---

Now there are a couple natural variations to the above notion:

- What if we demand *inequality* instead of *equality*?
- What if we restrict attention to machines with *binary* output?

Both of these variations prevent the argument above from working, the former by preventing us from representing runtimes as outputs and the latter by preventing us from coding literally *anything* into the output.

It turns out that these notions yield a much weaker complexity class: namely the [**PA degrees**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA_degree). The original definition was that something is of PA degree if it computes a complete consistent extension of Peano arithmetic (which by Godel must be non-computable), but there are many equivalent definitions. Generally the simplest to work with is:

> A [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) ${\bf a}$ is PA iff whenever $X$ is an infinite computable binary tree, ${\bf a}$ computes an infinite path through $X$.

PA degrees can be quite weak, computability-theoretically. While no PA degree is computable, they don't have to compute the halting problem: there are PA degrees incomparable with the halting problem, and there are PA degrees strictly weaker than the halting problem (where strength here is measured by [Turing reducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction)).

---

Re: relativization, the answer is **no**: the proof of the incomputability of all PA degrees relativizes, so no oracle is PA over itself.

Comment: `keep in mind that Te's output on input e might be unrelated to the runtime of Te(e).` Yet the output *can* be the runtime, so I don't quie understand the part

Comment: We can write function $g$ that output how many steps to run $f$

Comment: @l4m2 Ouch! That's embarrassing. When I get a moment I'll repair this answer, but very briefly: if we look instead at functions which *avoid* the value, or restrict attention to $\{0,1\}$-valued Turing machines, then the statements above are correct. I was writing without thinking and failed to realize that I was mixing up circumstances.

Comment: How do you show that the two variants are strictly weaker than the halting problem?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Consider the tree $D$ of finite binary sequences where a binary sequence $\sigma$ of length $n$ is on $T$ iff for each $k<n$, it is **not** the case that running $T_k(k)$ for $n$ steps halts and yields $\sigma(k)$. Infinite paths through $D$ are exactly the $\{0,1\}$-valued functions which avoid every recursive function in the desired way ("diagonally nonrecursive on $\{0,1\}$," or "DNR$_2$"). Now apply the low basis theorem.

Comment: That does the former case, where we want to avoid the functions' outputs. But by staying in $\{0,1\}$ we've also shown how to do the latter: look at the "dual" tree where we replace $\sigma(k)$ by $1-\sigma(k)$.

Comment: Is the avoid oracle strictly weaker or equal to the binary oracle?

Comment: @l4m2 It is **strictly weaker**. There is a hierarchy here: the **diagonally non-recursive** (DNR) (or **non-computable** (DNC)) functions. This hierarchy comes from restricting the codomain: a DNR$_k$ function for $k$ a natural $>1$ is a (total) function $f$ with codomain $\{0,...,k-1\}$ such that for each computable $T_e$ we have $T_e(e)\downarrow\rightarrow T_e(e)\not=f(e)$. A DNR function is one with no codomain restriction at all. These form a proper hierarchy in terms of strength: every DNR$_k$ computes a DNR$_{k+1}$ but not conversely and every DNR$_k$ computes a DNR but not conversely.

Comment: (Keep in mind that per my comments above, the binary version is equivalent to DNR$_2$, so this really is capturing everything above.) [Downey/Hirschfeldt's book](https://www.amazon.com/Algorithmic-Randomness-Complexity-Applications-Computability/dp/0387955674) contains a ton of information about these and other related notions.

Comment: Late acception because I thought you used the wrong reduction and got wrong result, then know it should be some other mistake